# How to find the matrix of the Linear Tranformation wrt the bases S and T?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let L: $\mathbb{R}^4$ -> $\mathbb{R}^3$ be defined by

$$L
\left(
\left[
\begin{matrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3 \\
x_4
\end{matrix}
\right]
\right)
=
\left[
\begin{array}{rrrrr}
1 &  0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 &  1 & 2 & 1 \\
-1 &  -2 & 1 & 0
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{matrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3 \\
x_4
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

$$
S
=
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrrr}
\left[
\begin{matrix}
1\\
1\\
0\\
0
\end{matrix}
\right],
\left[
\begin{matrix}
0\\
1\\
0\\
0
\end{matrix}
\right],
\left[
\begin{matrix}
0\\
0\\
1\\
1
\end{matrix}
\right],
\left[
\begin{matrix}
0\\
1\\
1\\
0
\end{matrix}
\right]
\end{array}
\right)
$$

and

$$
T
=
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrrr}
\left[
\begin{matrix}
1\\
0\\
1
\end{matrix}
\right],
\left[
\begin{matrix}
0\\
1\\
1
\end{matrix}
\right],
\left[
\begin{matrix}
0\\
0\\
1
\end{matrix}
\right]
\end{array}
\right)
$$

be the ordered bases for the $\mathbb{R}^4$ -> $\mathbb{R}^3$, respectively. Find the matrix of linear transformation with respect to the bases S and T.

Any idea is appreciated. I couldnt find much examples in the internet and I was not around when this thing was explained in our class.

---

**EDIT**: Here's what I have so far:

This is my solution for L(u2) and L(u3). Correct me if im wrong.

[image]

Comment: should i take the reduced form of bases S and T first?

Comment: What is called the *reduced form* of bases?

Comment: @user66240 You'll need to find three different transformations and compose them.  The first will take vectors in $\Bbb R^4$ from their representation wrt the $S$ basis to their representation wrt the standard basis.  Your next transformation will just be $L$ in the standard bases of $\Bbb R^4$ and $\Bbb R^3$.  Your last transformation will be take vectors in $\Bbb R^3$ from their standard basis representations to their representations wrt the $T$ basis.  Can you see how to find the first and last transformations?  Do you understand how to compose matrix transformations?

Comment: yes thank you!!

Comment: please wait for a moment i need you to check my work :)

Comment: @Bye_World, can you check my work? its in the answers :)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Let's call $X, Y$, &c., the matrix columns of vectors in the canonical bases, and $X', Y'$, &c. the matrix columns of the same vectors in the new bases. We have:
$$\begin{cases}Y=LX\\X=SX'\\Y=TY' \end{cases}$$
Just express the relation between the new coordinates of vectors from the first relation, with the help of the last two:
$$Y=TY'=LX=L(SX')=(LS)X',\enspace\text{whence}\enspace Y'=(T^{-1}LS)X'.$$
(Matrices $L$  and $L'$ that satisfy a relation $L'=PLQ$ for invertible matrices $P$ and $Q$ are said to be *equivalent*).

Comment: i still dont get it sir :(

Comment: I added some computation details. Is that clearer?

Comment: i very much appreciate your work sir but, i cant really figure it out. im kind of hate math. i get easily confused especially you changing the variables on your hints.

Comment: ??? I didn't change the variables, I just introduced some *general* notations. The key point is that the coordinates of a vector will change if you change the basis. Do you agree with that?

Comment: ill to decode your hints. its still not clear enough, well not clear enough for me (first time solving for matrix rpresentation).

Comment: but im really glad you helped sir :)

Answer (score 1):

The matrix

$\left[
\begin{array}{rrrrr}
1 &  0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 &  1 & 2 & 1 \\
-1 &  -2 & 1 & 0
\end{array}
\right]$

is the **standard matrix** of $L$, that is, the matrix of L with respect to the standard bases $\{ e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4\}$ on $\mathbf{R}^4$ and $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ on $\mathbf{R}^4$. This follows from the fact that the standard matrix is given by

$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
| & | & | & | \\ 
L(e_1) & L(e_2) & L(e_3) & L(e_4)\\
| & | & | & |
\end{matrix}
\right].
$

To find the matrix of $L$ with respect to some other bases $S=\{ u_1, u_2, u_3, u_4 \}$ of $\mathbf{R}^4$ and $T=\{w_1,w_2,w_3\}$ of $\mathbf{R}^3$, we need to modify the above recipe using coordinates. The columns of the matrix will be built out of the images of the vectors in $S$, not the vectors in the standard basis. So we need to compute

$L(u_1), L(u_2), L(u_3), L(u_4)$

which you can do using the standard matrix. However, since we don't want to use the standard coordinates on $\mathbf{R}^3$, we need to write those image vectors in $T$-coordinates :

$[L(u_1)]_T, [L(u_2)]_T, [L(u_3)]_T, [L(u_4)]_T$.

Finally, our modified recipe for the matrix of $L$ with respect to these special bases $S,T$ is

$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
| & | & | & | \\ 
[L(u_1)]_T & [L(u_2)]_T & [L(u_3)]_T & [L(u_4)]_T\\
| & | & | & |
\end{matrix}
\right].
$

Comment: can you check my work? :)

Answer (score 0):

Say $S=(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4)$, where $v_j$'s are the column vectors in $\Bbb R^4$ and $T=(w_1,w_2,w_3)$, where $w_i$'s are the column vectors in $\Bbb R^3$. Then calculate $L(v_j)$ and express it in terms of $w_1,w_2$ and $w_3$. Say, $L(v_j)=a_{1j}w_1+a_{2j}w_2+a_{3j}w_3$, for each $j=1,\dotsc,4$. Then the matrix of $L$ w.r.t the bases $S$ and $T$ is the matrix $(a_{ij})$ .

Comment: should i take the reduced form of bases S and T first?

Comment: What is meant for "reduced form of bases"?

Comment: To take its RREF.

Comment: It is not necessary. If this is what you are studying for the first time, you should express $L(v_j)$ in terms of $w_i$'s.